# why follow path with duplication not in curve shape

Tags: path

I have a icosphere and a rectangle path. With the follow path selecting icosphere and path. Ctrl+P i made a follow path. In the properties of icosphere i on the duplication to frame. The icosphere not in rectangle path. Shape missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Frame duplication is pre-2.8.. what version of Blender is your file?

Comment: @RobinBetts 2.79 old verison